# loading data into X_train and Y_train

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

If this is the organisation of my data how would I load this data in to x_train and y_train to make a keras model

train.zip

The image files for the training set

train.txt

The labels for the training set

test.zip

The image files for the test set

[image]

This is how train.txt looks like

These are how the zip files look:

[image]

I am fumbled of how I should load this data so I can have numpy arrays for x_train, y_train and x_test and y_test so I can make a CNN model. I've tried many things but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Image Data Generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).
You will want to unzip your files and add a column header to the txt file.
So for example like this:

```
Filename Label
train/0.jpg 5
train/1.jpg 21
```

Now you can use pandas to read the txt file then use the ImageDataGenerator:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("uos-com2028/train/train.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
columns = [
     "Label",
]
# you may want to rescale your image if it goes from 0 to 255
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
     rescale=1./255.,
)
# you will want to change color_mode, batch_size, and target_size depending on your image
traindata = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
   dataframe=df,
   directory="uos-com2028/train",
   x_col="Filename",
   y_col=columns,
   color_mode='rgb',
   batch_size=16,
   class_mode="raw",
   target_size=(256, 256),
   shuffle=True,
)
```

You can then use the traindata object as your training input when running model.fit()

Comment: thanks, i'll try this out, if you don't mind can i contact you via email so i can send you a kaggle link so we can try this together. i'm so lost

Comment: yeah no problem. You can contact me via endermanaresassy@gmail.com